# Static webpage in s3 bucket and making ajax request inside the page to call lambda function

Tags: ajax, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have uploaded a html page in s3 bucket and that html page makes an ajax post request to the api gateway url to send an email.

The problem is that the same api gateway url if I use postman to make a post request to it the email is sent but with the html page in s3 having ajax code doesn't work.

Any idea, or help will be helpful for me. Thanks
----Ajax code

```
    $.ajax("https://apigateway-url/email_sending", {
    "type": "POST",
    "data": JSON.stringify(formData),
    "contentType": "application/json"
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Done")
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Failed");
        // console.log(data);
    });
```

I have tried so many help from net like edit cors configuration in s3 or enable cors in api gateway, but none worked for me.

NodeJs code for send Email

```
    var sendemail = require('./sendemail')
    app.post('/email_sending',function(req,res){
     console.log("Request received For sending mail")
     sendemail.send(req.body,function(err, data){

   // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.end("Success");
   })

  })
```

sendemail module snippet is :

```
    ses.sendemail(data, done)
```

I considered this website but didn't get the solution : https://codehabitude.com/2016/04/05/forms-to-emails-using-aws-lambda-api-gateway/

Comment: Enabling CORS in API Gateway is the main thing you need to do here, and it sounds like you already have done that. You need to capture some debugging information using the browser's developer console to ensure that the AJAX call happens and doesn't receive an error, and using logging in the Lambda function to ensure it is being invoked and that it doesn't throw an error or exit abruptly.

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely you aren't setting up the CORS headers correctly in apigateway. The apigateway documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html clearly describes the process.

Once you've setup CORS and deployed the changes, you can verify the CORS preflight request using the below curl command

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
  -X OPTIONS --verbose \
    https://apigateway-url/email_sending
```

Also, note that you need to deploy the changes after you setup CORS (Big blue Deploy API button - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api-with-console.html) before the change is reflected in your API